# Creating a custom input field with Web Components without outside accessability

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I want to create a custom input with the Shadow DOM

```
class TextBox extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    let textbox = document.createElement("input");
    shadow.appendChild(textbox);
    textbox.addEventListener("change", validate);

    function validate(event) {
      console.log("input can be validated");
    }
  }
  get value() {
    console.log("get");
    let textbox = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("input");
    return textbox.value;
  }
  set value(newValue) {
    console.log("set");
    let textbox = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("input");
    textbox.value = newValue;
  }
}
customElements.define('test-textbox', TextBox);
```

It should be possible to change the value of the displayed textbox via js. If I change the `.value` property of the textbox the setter of value don't get called? Am i missing something?

Later on I want to include the textbox via a template in my solution and be able to set the value of the textbox via `textbox.value ="Peter"`

Comment: It's working without problem https://jsfiddle.net/6vgw97qh/

Comment: But the set or get methods do not fire?

Comment: check the console it's working

Comment: I meant when i change the content of the textbox, the set value method won't fire.

Comment: that is normal instead you can do `textbox.addEventListener("input", function_name);`

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal `<input>` field dispatches the `input` event every time its value changes. This event can be captured either in your component or by the code that uses your component.

The `change` event only happens in certain situations so the `input` event is a better choice.

The code below shows how the component listens for the `input` event and so does the external code.

```js
function validate(event) {
  console.log("input can be validated");
}

class TextBox extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadow.innerHTML = `
    <style>
      input {
        width: 300px;
      }
    </style>
    `;
    const textbox = document.createElement("input");
    shadow.appendChild(textbox);
    textbox.addEventListener("input", validate);
    textbox.focus();
  }

  get value() {
    console.log("get");
    let textbox = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("input");
    return textbox.value;
  }
  set value(newValue) {
    console.log("set");
    let textbox = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("input");
    textbox.value = newValue;
  }
}

customElements.define('test-textbox', TextBox);

const el = document.querySelector('test-textbox');
el.addEventListener("input", (evt) => {
  console.log('input event from the outside.');
});
```

```html
<test-textbox></test-textbox>
```